# Problem with SKTexture in Swift 5 - Insufficient Memory (IOAF code 8)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a problem using SpriteKit in my code.
I am loading some pixel art images and then using SpriteKit to show them scaled without anti-aliasing, it works well but randomly I get this error:

Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Insufficient Memory (IOAF code 8)

When this happens the app doesn't crash, but the sceneView is empty.
This is the portion of the code that should be of interest. Is there something I am missing?

```
let sceneView = SKView()
sceneView.allowsTransparency = true
sceneView.frame = imageView.frame
let scene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: contentView.frame.width, height: contentView.frame.height))
scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:  0, y: 0)
let boxTexture = SKTexture(image: UIImage(named: "box.png")!)
boxTexture.filteringMode = .nearest
let boxSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: boxTexture)
boxSprite.position = CGPoint(x: contentView.frame.width/2, y:  contentView.frame.height/2)
boxSprite.size = CGSize(width: contentView.frame.width, height: contentView.frame.height)
boxSprite.zPosition = 1
            
scene.addChild(boxSprite)
scene.addChild(sprite)
scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
contentView.addSubview(sceneView)
sceneView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
sceneView.presentScene(scene)
```

Comment: Are you seeing this on a device or a simulator? I remember seeing something like this if the target device wasn't on Metal but probably unrelated.

Comment: just on the device (iPhone 12 pro, iOS 14.3), I tried now on the simulator and it seems to work fine